# Assign "div id" value to the variable php

Tags: php, html, variables, variable-assignment

I have a div on my page '.php'

```
<div id="force_id"></div>
```

This prints an id for each product on the page. Ex: 126500

How do I assign this value of the other PHP variable (not click, on load for example)

I use it here :

```
$limit = ??????   (Value should be the id value here. For example 126500)
$plans = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from motors WHERE prod_id = '$limit'"));
```

Thank you in advance ...

Comment: I'm not sure anyone will help until you've replaced the deprecated mysql_ functions with mysqli_ equivalents.

Comment: Assing in PHP: `$limit = 126500`. Than in HTML `<div id="force_id_<?php echo $limit; ?>"></div>`

Comment: PHP and page communication is only ever one way, the PHP never sees the page, it runs the code and *THEN*  the page is generated, so it can't use any information from the page structure. To assign page values to PHP you'll need to use GET or POST events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for something on-load then you will need to use Javascript with some sort of Ajax call.

Your javascript would need to grab the id and then pass that to .php as a POST or GET variable.

However, it would probably be better for you to pass the ID with the page request.  So your link to .php would look like this:

```
<a href='page.php?id=126500'>Link</a>
```

Obviously you can auto generate these.  Then in .php you just get the value from GET:

```
$limit = $_GET['id']
```

Then you can use it in your SQL query (you should look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) rather than mysql_query to protect yourself from SQL injection hacks).

---

Some more detail on the GET option.
Your initial HTML for the menu choice of products to look at would look like this:

```
<h1>Select the Product you want to see</h1>
<ul>
<?php
$result = /*  SELECT MY PRODUCT CODES */

foreach($result AS $row){
    echo "<li><a href='product.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Product  ".$row['name']."</a></li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Then your product.php file would have this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $limit=$_GET['id'];
    $plans= /* SELECT FROM MOTORS USING $limit */
    foreach($plans AS $row){
            echo 'Product name:'.$row['name'];
            echo "<img src='".$row['img_path']."' />";
            ...
     }

}else{
    echo 'Sorry, unrecognised product';
}
```

You should do further validation on $_GET['id']; for example check that it is a number and within a range that you would expect for your product_id's

---

More detail on the POST option using Javascript & JQuery.
If you have a specific reason for wanting to do POST, or for some reason you only want to publish the ID code on the one page then you could do it like this:

In your HTML I would use a data attribute in a div:

```
<div id='product' data-id='12650'></div>
```

In Javascript (I've assumed JQuery but the approach would be the same with other libraries) you would add to your 'onload' function (i.e. do this after the page has loaded):

```
$('#product').each(function(){
     var id=$(this).data('id');
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'product_content.php',
        data: {'id':id},
        success: function(msg){
             $(this).html(msg);
         },
        error: function(msg, status,err){
             $(this).html("Product not Found");             
         }
     });            
});
```

Finally you need a page to respond to the Ajax call product_content.php :

```
$limit=$_POST['id'];
/* DO SOME VALIDATION ON $limit HERE OR USE PDO AS PROTECTION */
$plans= /* SELECT FROM MOTORS USING $limit*/
 foreach($plans AS $row){
    echo 'Product name:'.$row['name'];
    echo "<img src='".$row['img_path']."' />";
    ...
}
```

I should point out I've not tested this code, so keep an eye out for typo's if you copy it directly.

Comment: Dear AntG . Is it possible to make such an example to me.

Comment: @Extropy I've added further detail to my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're using form, you can put the div's value inside an `input[hidden]` inside the form. Something like this:

```
  $('#your_form').on('submit', function(){
    your_div = $('#your_div').attr('id');
    $('#hidden_field_used_on_form').val(your_div);
    return true;
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not use form.